# Add Connection String as a parameter to setup.msi in visual studio setup projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a situation to pass connection string as a parameter to the msi file so that the installer picks it up and replace the connection string in .exe.config file.

I can easily achieve this by using a custom action to do the same thing. But I don't want to use it since I have some limitations of not using them. So is it possible to such thing without using custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have no limitations I did on several projects. what I do is I also indexes my connection on an environment variable (other solution), to avoid to deploy multiple versions of the software.

Comment: Yeah... thank you for your reply Aghilas... :)
What I meant by "having limitations" is that I am not allowed to use custom actions!!!

Comment: But I am confused bit about your answer yet. Can you bit elaborate it more?

Comment: if you want deploy your projet wih string connection prametrized, you can use custom action in order to pass in parameter your string connection.

Comment: you can also in your data access layer get string connection by using environment variable, for example if your environment variable is Dev(this name), you connect your service with string connection of dev that match with nvironment variable, if staging you take string connection of staging.  with this solution you must have all string connection in your app.config,,,and the client must adjust his environment variable.

Comment: According to your first approach, I have to use to a custom action. But The option of using a custom action is not available to me. What I really want is to provide the msi with a connection string when it is being executed (something like setup.msi -C <connection-string>).If I take this kind of approach, would the setup use this connection string and use it in the application?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any native support in Windows Installer for transforming XML files.  You'll have to use a custom action of some sort or remove the requirement that the installer perform the update.

The cleanest way to do it while still using (mostly) visual studio setup and deployment projects would be to author a WiX merge module to encapsulate the XML change piece and consume the module in your installer.